# Tools for reversible file splitting in a directory?

Tags: backup

Is there a tool that does this:

```
tool --inplace --split . --larger-than 50M # [1]
# recursively find files larger than 50 MB and split them into <= 50 MB chunks,
# removes original file
# store the mapping between original files and chunks in a special file in the dir, say tool.db
```

```
tool --inplace --restore . --db tool.db
# completely reverses the process above
```

```
tool --split . --output-dir ../outdir
# like [1], but doesn't touch ., outdir should look exactly like . in [1] after command [1] completes
```

Comment: Sounds like your demand "store the mapping between original files and chunks in a special file" can be covered by standard compression tools where have the option to generate chunks like `original.zip`, `original.zip.001`, `original.zip.002` and so on. Note that in that case compression can also be disabled. Probably all you need is a handy shell script. Please note your operating system.

Comment: @jmizv Thanks for the suggestion! What if I don't want compression, just splitting?

Comment: This should be possible, too. I remember that I have recently split a big mp4 file in order to put it on my FAT32 USB stick in chunks smaller 4GB. I've used 7-Zip on Win for that. So, yes, you can use an option "no compression" for that.